# Cast function failing from derived table SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I've got one table with alphanumeric codes.  In this particular instance, I am not concerned with the codes that are alphanumeric in nature, only those that contains integers.  I wrote a small query to find a the subset of codes that I needed:

```
 select CAST(icd as float) as icd

from
(
select i.icd
    from icd as i
    where icd like '952%' or icd like '806%' or icd like '3440%' or icd like '3441'
)t
```

This returns me a list of the codes I needed.  However, when I try to use a where clause like:

`where icd between 80600 and 80610` the query fails, telling me that it can't convert the varchar datatype to int.  However, if I do something like

```
select CAST(icd as float) as icd,icd+10

from
(
select i.icd
    from icd as i
    where icd like '952%' or icd like '806%' or icd like '3440%' or icd like '3441'
)t
```

I can add ten to each code and it runs, meaning that they are in fact integers.  I want to use the `where` clause like this because codes 80600-80610 should be labeled X and 80611-80620 they should be labeled Y.  I can do this manually for each code, but I'd like to be more extensible than that.

How can I make sure that SQL Server only looks at the derived table when using this where clause, instead of failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Filters run before results are cast

What you're doing is casting results not column values when query runs (and does all the filtering). Filters (`where` clause) are evaluated before result values are being cast.

In order to still work with the same result set as you show in your example the easiest way is to use a CTE instead of a sub-query and then do additional filtering on that:

```
with codes as (
    select cast(icd as int) as icd
    from icd
    where icd like '952%' or
          icd like '806%' or
          icd like '3440%' or
          icd like '3441'
)
select icd, 'X' as label
from codes
where icd between 80600 and 80610
union all
select icd, 'Y'
from codes
where icd between 80611 and 80620
```

Whether CTEs are more/less readable than sub-queries is a matter of endless discussion/arguments. But in this case where we reuse the same table expression to get **X** and **Y** labelled results it uses less code compared to what would be needed when doing the same with sub-queries. In this case it is by far more readable.

### Data to be cast must be numeric of course

When you're casting data you have to make sure it actually can be cast to result type. If your value is `064 V` this is clearly not a number hence can't be cast. a call to `isnumeric` can help here:

```
with codes as (
    select cast(icd as int) as icd
    from icd
    where isnumeric(icd) = 1 and
          (
              icd like '952%' or
              icd like '806%' or
              icd like '3440%' or
              icd like '3441'
          )
)
select icd, 'X' as label
from codes
where icd between 80600 and 80610
union all
select icd, 'Y'
from codes
where icd between 80611 and 80620
```

Comment: this returned the same error as i was given originally: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '064 V' to data type int.`

Comment: @wootscootinboogie the error is true, you cannot convert a string (*which is not a valid numeric format*).

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: I edited my answer to include an additional filter that will ensure that data actually **can** be cast to numeric type.

Comment: i think the cte is readable, and I like the `ISNUMERIC` function, i hadn't learned about that yet.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: I included that in my answer as well because you didn't say anything about invalid non-numeric data in your question.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie: I also added your labels. CTE's make union-ing two results over the same expression super simple. It would need much more code to do the same using sub-queries.

Comment: [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors).

Comment: @HABO: Nice find this bug report. So if my second CTE query raises an error, a suggested `case` statement should do the trick.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - There seem to be enough issues with `case` (e.g. [CASE / COALESCE won't always evaluate in textual order](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/690017/case-coalesce-wont-always-evaluate-in-textual-order) and [Aggregates Don't Follow the Semantics Of CASE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/691535/aggregates-dont-follow-the-semantics-of-case)) that the only safe solution appears to be making one pass that segregates the data, e.g. into a temporary table or by setting flags in rows, and a second pass to process the validated subset.

Comment: @HABO: Would using a double CTE do the trick here or are CTEs executed *in place*? I could of course check with query execution plan what the execution would look like, but you seem to already know the answer...

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - Most problems with `CASE` seem to involve aggregate functions, but my confidence is shrinking.  See [SQL Server should not raise illogical errors](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) for more examples.  So far the most horrifying is the lack of support for integer arithmetic: `select 30 / 3 / 5; select 30 / 3 / -5; select 30 / -3 / 5`.  (This is actually a special case.  Microsoft slipped up and _documented_ the expected behavior of arithmetic operators.  They simply didn't bother implementing it.)

Answer (score 3):

your inner query is probably returning varchar fields. Can you run

```
select i.icd
from icd as i
where icd like '952%' or icd like '806%' or icd like '3440%' or icd like '3441'
```

and make sure no string data is being returned?

FYI, since you are using an inner query, you could add

```
WHERE IsNumeric(t.icd ) = 1
```

to be sure only integers are being returned

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your where filter treats ICD as a string (which it is), and then filter only those ICD's which are convertible to numeric.

Of special note is that is that string comparisons need to take note of the 'length' of your number (e.g. '8061' lies between '80600' and '80610'), but fortunately it seems that your filter lies within a range where the length is constant.

e.g.

```
where icd between '80600' and '80610' -- i.e. exclude '12345' and 'Apple'
      and length(icd) = 5             -- i.e. exclude '8061' and '806000001'
      and isnumeric(icd) = 1          -- i.e. exclude '8060A'
```